# Fiat 500 (2010) airbag replace - crash sensor help

Tags: sensor, supplemental-restraint-system, fiat

Recently replaced airbags in a fiat 500 1.2L (2010 model). I've also cleared the crash codes/data from ECU.

I assume I would have to replace the front crash sensor as well, but couldn't locate it. The following link (although a different year and engine size) suggests it's under the front slam panel.

http://www.fiatonlineparts.com/a/Fiat__50014L-I4-MultiAir-Turbo--6-Spd-Aisin-F21-250-HD-Auto-TransL-TREKKING/61624596__6591792/Module--Impact-Sensors--Air-Bag/i2322911.html

Is there anywhere else it might be or are there any tips on how to locate it?

Also I found this link which seems to suggest there is a sensor underneath the steering column. Would this also need replacing?

http://www.fiatonlineparts.com/a/Fiat__50014L-I4-MultiAir-Turbo--6-Spd-Aisin-F21-250-HD-Auto-TransL-TREKKING/61624596__6549443/Air-Bags-Modules---Impact-Sensors-and-Clock-Spring/i2323680.html

So my main question is, do I need to replace the crash sensor and if so where would it be on the particular model I'm working on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having the same problem did you figure it out